# Edit Vuejs data from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I’m using Vue.JS with two components and two templates. They are being used multiple times:

```
<compone v-show="! showcompone"></compone>
<compone v-show="! showcomptwo"></compone>
```

and

```
<comptwo v-show="! showcompone"></comptwo>
<comptwo v-show="! showcomptwo"></comptwo>
```

My vuejs is as follows:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
        return {
            showcompone: true,
            showcomptwo: true,
        }
    }
});
```

What I need to know is: how do I make my components toggle `v-show`’s `data` on click? How can I be able to change the `data` property value through components?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue can handle events for you, just use the `v-on` directive, or the shorthand `@` on your component, for example:

```
<button @click="showcompone = !showcompone">Toggle one</button>
<button @click="showcomptwo = !showcomptwo">Toggle two</button>
```

what you pass to the `@click` event is pure javascript, so you can call a function or whatever you want with js

Comment: Although, I'm sure that I've read Evan (VueJS developer) advocate against assignment of values in HTML because it's harder to reason. Suggest calling a method instead of assignments directly in the HTML.

Comment: Hmm... But how can I do this? Can I pass object to methods functions?

Comment: If your logic for the click event get complicatted, it gets difficult to read it inline. So the best attempt, as @TremendusApps says, is to define a dedicated method in the `methods` property of your component, and then call it like `@click="methodName"` in your click bind

Comment: In case that you need arguments for your method, just do `@click="methodName(arg1, arg2, ...)"`. you also have access to the function event in the `$event` var

Comment: I tried this, but don't work. :/ My method are: `methodName:(arg , event){ arg = !arg}`.

Comment: should be `methodName: function (arg, event = null) { arg = !arg }`. But, if the arg that you are passing is part of your component `data` then you should just do `methodName: function () { this.arg != this.arg }`

Comment: I tried this, but the `arg` change the value. But still don't work. I think the `arg` in method belongs to another contexto. So my `data` in Vue App don't change. :/

I will try again. Thanks Yerko! :)

Comment: I solved this with: `@click="methodName('arg', $event)"` and `methodName: function(arg, event = null){this[arg] = true)`

It's not a really good solution, but it's works. xD